# Call sidekiq worker from separate process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabbitmq, sidekiq

I have an ordinary sidekiq worker in the rails project directory. It should work as a listener and trigger every time new data appears in the RabbitMQ queue. To optimize the project, it was decided to move the listening of messages from RabbitMQ into a separate process, and from there to call a worker in the main project.

The question is how can I send a task from a separate process to rails sidekiq project?

Or if you have other ideas how to implement this, tell me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to push a job to Redis that Sidekiq will understand:

```
require 'securerandom'
require 'json'

redis = Redis.new(:url => 'redis://hostname:port/db')
msg = { "class" => 'MyWorker',
    "queue" => 'default',
    "args" => [1, 2, 3],
    'retry' => true,
    'jid' => SecureRandom.hex(12),
    'created_at' => Time.now.to_f,
    'enqueued_at' => Time.now.to_f }
redis.lpush("queue:default", JSON.dump(msg))
```

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-push-a-job-to-sidekiq-without-ruby

Answer (score 1):

Sidekiq manages tasks through its queue, which is in Redis. As long as both processes are talking to the same Redis instance, this should Just Work.